# LIKE operator and correct usage with NOT IN

Tags: php, mysql, field, sql-like

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

This currently works...

```
$resultInput = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $table. " WHERE Field NOT IN ('id', 'created', 'date_modified', 'content', 'type', 'bodytext', 'project_content', 'content_short') AND Field NOT LIKE '%_image%'");
```

However I would like to remove all the fields with the name content and add it to the LIKE function with something like `%content%`

```
$resultInput = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $table. " WHERE Field NOT IN ('id', 'created', 'date_modified', 'type', 'bodytext') AND Field NOT LIKE ('%_image%', %content%)");
```

But this doesn`t seem to work? and returns a"

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
>           C:\xampp\htdocs\framework.php on line 33

Comment: missing single quotes around %content% ?? and you have two items in the not like I think you need to put and not like twice, once for each

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are attempting is actually a syntax error. `LIKE` conditions must be individually listed and separated by `AND` or `OR`. In your case however, you can do it [with `REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) by separating the conditions with `|`:

```
SHOW COLUMNS 
FROM " . $table. " 
WHERE Field NOT IN ('id', 'created', 'date_modified', 'type', 'bodytext') 
AND Field NOT REGEXP '_image|content'
```

Because the regular expression will match the patterns `content` or `_image` *anywhere* inside `Field`, there is no need for any additional equivalent characters to the `%` wildcards used in `LIKE`.

We assume that `$table` has been compared against a list of valid table names to use in this query for security purposes.

Finally, you received the fatal error *`mysql_num_rows()` expects parameter 1 to be resource* because you performed no error checking on the query result.

```
$result_input = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS.....");
if (!$result_input) {
  // Something's wrong
  echo mysql_error();
}
else {
  // ok, everything is working, proceed.
}
```

Comment: very good solution! thanks man! what would one do when they want to include say content? AND Field REGEXP 'content'?

Comment: For example this query doesnt seem to be working....   $resultTextarea = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $table. " WHERE Field IN ('bodytext') AND Field REGEXP 'content'");

Comment: @AlexFagard If you want positive results rather than negative, you would need an `OR` as in `Field IN ('bodytext','somethingelse') OR Field REGEXP '_image|content'`.

Comment: @AlexFagard Don't use `REGEXP` for only one simple condition like `content` alone, as it is probably more efficient to use `LIKE`.

Comment: Thanks. Yea In my research I saw info on the greater efficiency of the like statement!